# Find corresponding 2d point on Right Image in Stereo Camera

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I have a point(xl,yl) in left image in a stereo camera. I want to determine where this same point maps in the right image let's say point(xr,yr) in right image.I have all the rotational matrices & translation matrices using camera calibration using opencv.

Comment: At what depth? A pixel in one image determines a 3D ray out its camera, which maps to  a line in the other image (the "epipolar line" of the first pixel). By selecting a depth (or estimating one, using one of many stereo matching methods) you fix a point on the ray, hence a corresponing pixel in the epipolar line.

Comment: Actually, I was trying not to do disparity map using cvstereocorrespondencebm, I thought if there is some function or some matrix which we multiply to get the same corresponding point on the right image.Finally I want (x2 - x1), disparity output.

Comment: Nope, no such thing - it obviously cannot exist.

Comment: @Aizen, had you managed to figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with simple 2D Point Matching. I got something like this in OpenFrameworks working:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> ext = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("ORB");

cv::Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

//The images are cv::Mat and the Points are std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>> which I got from cv::FASTX()
ext->compute(_leftImage, _leftPoints, descriptors_1);
ext->compute(_rightImage, _rightPoints, descriptors_2);

cv::BFMatcher matcher;

std::vector<cv::DMatches> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);
```

`matches` then has references to the fitting pairs of points in each image. It would still need some cleaning to get rid of outliers (all the correct matches should be parallel to each other ;) ), but with some work you should be able to rectify the two images to each other.